# Why was the Dominion v. Fox case tried in Delaware?

Tags: jurisdiction, delaware

As reported, [Fox News is sued in the Delaware courts by Dominion.](https://abcnews.go.com/US/dominion-case-fox-news-trial-judge-rules/story?id=98276968)

What determines which state(s) the Dominion v. Fox case is tried?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Delaware is the leading place of incorporation for publicly held corporations (about 60% of them) https://www.fool.com/investing/general/2014/12/21/why-60-of-public-companies-are-incorporated-in-thi.aspx , but this is not true of privately held corporations which are overwhelmingly incorporated in the state where their headquarters are located. Also, fun fact, the New York Stock Exchange is a cooperative corporation rather than an investor owned corporation.

Answer (score 18):

The defendant Fox corporation (there are a variety of affiliated or formerly affiliated companies with very similar names) is organized under the laws of Delaware so lawsuits related to its activities anywhere in the world may be brought in that forum. This choice of venue denied Fox any means of contesting jurisdiction or venue.

Also, the Delaware courts have a great level of expertise in handling litigation involving publicly held corporations. While this may not have been very important for a jury trial on the merits itself, this expertise was quite relevant in the pre-trial discovery phase of the trial which alleged widespread misconduct by the inner circle of a publicly held company's employees and officers.

Comment: One could ask a certain blue bird merger billionaire how bloody efficient Delaware's Court of Chancery (https://courts.delaware.gov/chancery/) is. The other courts in the same state don't fall short either.

Comment: I live in a state that doesn't have a Court of Chancery and has no need for one. Delaware does because many corporations are nominally based there. Anyway, I first read that as "Court of Chicanery" and for perhaps 1/10 of a second thought it was a fine joke.

Comment: @Wastrel The other states don't need a court of Chancery because Delaware handles 99% of the Chancery cases in record speed.

Comment: @Trish There are handful of other states with courts called Courts of Chancery, e.g. Wyoming. Other states have "business courts" intended to serve the same purpose. Delaware's pre-eminence is to a great extent a historical accident and was driven by Philadelphia lawyers seeking to forum shop.

Comment: @Wastrel: This is because most states (and indeed, most common law jurisdictions) merged their courts of law and equity a long time ago, but Delaware never did.

Comment: Fun fact: There are literally more corporations in Delaware than there are people.